# Is it possible to set the width and height attributes of a Canvas ID to 90% of the window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm having trouble getting the window size to be 90% of the size of the screen with Sketch.js.

I tried using Javascript but it starts the canvas size as huge (way bigger then the specified size) then after I start drawing it gets to the expected size.

I have a cancel drawing button that closes out the drawing and it is on a touch-pad. Because of this, until the user starts drawing the cancel button is not visible.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzge8wd/)

---

```js
$('#mysketch').sketch();
$('canvas').attr('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
```

```html
<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>
<canvas id='mysketch' style="height:90%; width:100%; border: 1px solid black; "></canvas>
```

Comment: The values of `width` and `height` attributes must be integers, not strings with `px`. They set the intrinsic size of the `canvas`. Then you can resize it with CSS if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply declare a variable like this

```
var procentOfHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9;

$('#mysketch').sketch();
$('canvas').css('height', procentOfHeight + 'px');
```

I have edited the code and changed attr to css when you set the height. Now its working. Try the snippet below where I have a hight of 50%.

```js
var procentOfHeight = $(window).height() * 0.5;
    
    $('#mysketch').sketch();
    $('canvas').css('height', procentOfHeight + 'px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>
<canvas id='mysketch' style=" width:100%; border: 1px solid black; "></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried using a variable, but the canvas still re-sizes when trying to draw. Here is the JS Fiddle of your suggestion that I did: http://jsfiddle.net/mqzge8wd/4/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I've marked your answer as the correct answer. Hopefully this will help others if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `css` , setting `canvas` `height` to `90vh` , `width` to `90vw` . See [Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) , [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```js
$("#mysketch").sketch();
```

```css
canvas {
    height:90vh;
    width:90vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>
<canvas id='mysketch' style="height:90%; width:100%; border: 1px solid black; "></canvas>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mqzge8wd/3/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't include my original attempt but my original attempt was using the viewport height and width and setting the position to absolute, however it will still automatically re-size the drawing before you start drawing to a huge size and after you start drawing goes to the intended size.